# How do you pass a selection button into the params passed with a form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, bootstrap-4

How can you allow a btn-group's selection to be passed in with the other parameters when the form is submitted by the user?

To spare the drudgery of combing through my rather long-winded nested form, I'll break it out into a simple example.

Here, @list is part of a before_action controller callback that gathers a set of values for use. The idea here is to have each value present in @list offered to the user in a set of buttons or a button-group.

I've been able to get it to pass in the parameters using a radio_button, but that's largely because it allows for the use of .radio_button, like this:

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <%= @list.each do |bar_suggestion| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :bar, bar_suggestion, value: bar_suggestion %><%= bar_suggestion>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I try to instead use a "standard" Bootstrap button or btn-group, whenever I try to set the desired params hash with "name", it does not attach itself to the active form object, so it doesn't get passed in properly.

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <%= @list.each do |bar_suggestion| %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="foo_params[bar]" value=<%= bar_suggestion %>><%= bar_suggestion %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do tell it to reference back to the form object? I've tried using f.button instead of f.radio_button, but whenever I click on it, it works like a submit button in that it immediately submits the form rather than simply representing a selected button.

Is this where JavaScript comes into play? Is there a way to do it without JS?

Comment: The default value of the `type` attribute of a `<button>` is `submit` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) so maybe including `type: 'button'` in your `f.button` call would help.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse @muistooshort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with a complex form that contains many nested elements, in order for the button selection to be passed into the params that are posted with the form's submission, what is used for the name attribute is key (ie )

In my specific case, I was incorrectly assuming that the form object's progress through the chain of models also applied to the input tag whenever it was used.

So to give a specific example. Even though the form may look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :related_model_1 do |rm1| %>
    <%= rm1.fields_for :related_model_2 do |rm2| %>
      <%= rm2.fields_for :related_model_3 do |rm3| %>
```

... When it comes time to set up the input fields for the buttons, the full params "path" must be used for the name. So if related_model_3 has a field called "content" that we want the button's selection to set the value for, it may look something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="object[rm1][rm2][rm3][content]" ... >
```

Then, when the button is selected by the user and form is submitted, the value of the value attribute that is specified with the button will be passed in for the param path stated above in the name attribute.

If you ever want to double-check what you should be using for the name attribute, set up your button with the .radio_button method (ie `rm3.radio_button`), pull up the page and use F12 to inspect, then click through to the relevant source code to see what name attribute was generated for the radio_button.

I hope this helps anyone else who may be stumped on such an obvious answer! Thank you again to @muistooshort for your initial help and quick comment response!